# Vaadin Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, vaadin

I have a communication problem after doing anything which invokes Vaadin's server side, e.g. pressing the button. 
The application works properly on my local, no server push or other limitations was broken, my web.xml and appengine.xml:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Vaadin Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>300</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <description>Vaadin application class to start</description>
      <param-name>UI</param-name>
      <param-value>com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ast.web.viewer.AstWebViewer</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <application>checkstyle-ast-viewer</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Current link to application (with Vaadin's debug window):

http://checkstyle-ast-viewer.appspot.com/?debug

To reproduce my problem:

1. Enter any text to TextArea
2. Press the "Process" button.

Comment: What show in the log?

Comment: /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js?1417702603071
 A 2014-12-04 06:16:45.346 200 4.14 KB 78ms /?v-1417702603074
 A 2014-12-04 06:16:45.720 200 930.13 KB 301ms /VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet/A2C12FB327590BF2B233E941498F22DF.cache.js
 A 2014-12-04 06:16:45.864 200 1.67 KB 67ms /VAADIN/themes/base/common/img/loading-indicator.gif
 A 2014-12-04 06:16:47.793 200 336 B 70ms /VAADIN/themes/reindeer/common/img/horizontal-sprites.png
....

Comment: something like this, nothing special, no errors or even warnings

Comment: I had similar problem. Try disabling Push mode